# scrape with beautifulsoup the <a> not present in the result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

hello I try to **scrape** the url from a page to iterate in the catalogue and get all information like title description etc... I did this many times but on this site it seems the information is block somewhere
this is what I'm doing

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



url='https://www.stihl.fr/fr/p/tronconneuses-ms-180-54057#ms-180-54057'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4)        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}  

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup =BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
link = soup.find('a',class_='m_category-overview-tiles__item tile_product-standard')
print(link)
```

the html code look like this

```
<div class="m_category-overview-tiles__products animated faster fadeIn"><a href="/fr  /p/tronconneuses-ms-180-54057#ms-180-54057" class="m_category-overview-tiles__item tile_product-standard" data-test-id="product-tile-link"><div class="tile_product-standard__wrapper "><div class="tile_product-standard__image-wrapper"><div class="tile_product-standard__image-ratio"><picture class="tile_product-standard__image">
```

If someone can unlock this problem the seem block can not get it in the soup

thank you

Comment: Kindly mention the expected output as well in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your comment:

> hello thank you for this quick answer but I did a mistake the url is
> stihl.fr/fr/c/tronconneuses-98176 this one is the main category not
> the product from the main category i want **scrape** each product (that
> when i get the linkS I think i can handdle thank you again

#### What happens?

You try to scrape all links to the product details but choos `find()` that returns first result only.

#### How to fix?

Try `find_all()` instead to get all link elements as resultset:

```
soup.find_all('a',class_='m_category-overview-tiles__item tile_product-standard')
```

To store only the `href` in a list you can do the following:

```
links = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a',class_='m_category-overview-tiles__item tile_product-standard')]
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   

url='https://www.stihl.fr/fr/c/tronconneuses-98176'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4)        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}  

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup =BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
links = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a',class_='m_category-overview-tiles__item tile_product-standard')]
print(links)
```

#### Output

```
['/fr/p/tronconneuses-ms-180-54057#ms-180-54057', '/fr/p/tronconneuses-ms-170-2323#ms-170-2323', '/fr/p/tronconneuses-msa-140-systeme-ak-76261#c-b-sans-batterie-ni-chargeur-76261', '/fr/p/tronconneuses-mse-141-76267#mse-141-76267', '/fr/p/tronconneuses-msa-120-systeme-ak-73181#c-b-sans-batterie-ni-chargeur-73181', '/fr/p/tronconneuses-ms-181-1335#ms-181-1335', '/fr/p/tronconneuses-ms-251-1852#ms-251-1852', '/fr/p/tronconneuses-msa-200-gamme-ap-2173#c-b-sans-batterie-sans-chargeur-2173', '/fr/p/tronconneuses-msa-220-gamme-ap-102688#c-b-sans-batterie-sans-chargeur-102688',...]
```

#### Additional example to get title, subline, link in dict

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
    
url='https://www.stihl.fr/fr/c/tronconneuses-98176'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4)        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}  
    
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
soup =BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

data =[]

for item in soup.find_all('a',class_='m_category-overview-tiles__item tile_product-standard'):
    title = item.select_one('div.tile_product-standard__title').get_text()
    subline = item.select_one('div.tile_product-standard__subline').get_text()
    link = item['href']
    data.append({
        'title': title,
        'subline': subline,
        'link': link
    })
data
```

#### Output

```
[{'title': 'MS 180TRONÇONNEUSES',
  'subline': 'Tronçonneuse thermique pour la coupe de bois de chauffage avec tendeur de chaîne latéral',
  'link': '/fr/p/tronconneuses-ms-180-54057#ms-180-54057'},
 {'title': 'MS 170TRONÇONNEUSES',
  'subline': 'Idéale pour la coupe de bois de chauffage ou les petits travaux',
  'link': '/fr/p/tronconneuses-ms-170-2323#ms-170-2323'},
 {'title': 'MSA 140 - Système AKTRONÇONNEUSES',
  'subline': 'Produit vendu sans batterie ni chargeur',
  'link': '/fr/p/tronconneuses-msa-140-systeme-ak-76261#c-b-sans-batterie-ni-chargeur-76261'},...]
```

Comment: thank you mister I know the little difference for find and find_all but I don't know what I was doing wrong ... Really appreciate your kindness jerone

Comment: you provided different information in question and comment, so it is hard to understand what exactly is your issue - please improve your question, focus on one thing and show what result you expect. It would be easier to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is rendeered dynamically via JavaScript so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it (it's embedded in the tags in Json form). This example will parse some information about accessories from that page:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.stihl.fr/fr/p/tronconneuses-ms-180-54057"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = soup.select_one("product-accessories-component")["data-initial-state"]
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for r in data["results"]:
    print(r["headline"], "-", r["name"])
```

Prints:

```
STIHL Smart Connector - STIHL Smart Connector
Casque FUNCTION Basic - Casque FUNCTION Basic
Lunettes de protection DYNAMIC Contrast claires - Lunettes de protection DYNAMIC Contrast claires
Protège-oreilles CONCEPT 23 - Protège-oreilles CONCEPT 23
Salopette FUNCTION universal - Anti-coupures - Salopette FUNCTION universal
Gants DYNAMIC Duro - Gants DYNAMIC Duro
Pantalon FUNCTION Universal - Anti-coupures - Pantalon FUNCTION Universal
Chaussures anti-coupures FUNCTION - Chaussures anti-coupures FUNCTION
Carburant prêt à l'emploi pour moteurs 2-temps et 4-MIX® - Carburant MotoMix
Huile adhésive pour chaîne de tronçonneuse - Huile ForestPlus
Huile pour moteurs STIHL - Huile HP Super
Accessoire pour tronçonneuses - Clé multiple
Accessoire pour tronçonneuses - Outils Multifonctions
```

Comment: hello thank you for this quick answer but I did a mistake the url is https://www.stihl.fr/fr/c/tronconneuses-98176 this one is the main category not the product from the main category i want scrap each product (that when i get the linkS I think i can handdle thank you again